# Derive one inequality from another

Tags: inequality

One of the steps to the solution of my problem is to apply the following inequality:
$$\frac{y}{x} + \frac{x}{y} \ge 2$$
which is true for $x > 0$ and $y > 0$. 
My textbook suggests to use previously proven inequality $x + \dfrac{1}{x} \ge 2$ (for  $x > 0$) to get the one above.

By intuition, I understand how they are related. I wonder though if I could get the former inequality in a more formal way.

Comment: Let $z=y/x$. But $z+\frac1z\geq2$.

Comment: Put $z=x/y$ then $1/z=y/x$

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer so I could mark the question as answered?

Comment: @PaulVergeev Me?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let  $z=y/x$. But  $z+\dfrac1z\geq2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $0$, we can multiply the inequality by $xy$ to get

$y^2+x^2\ge2xy$

$y^2+x^2-2xy\ge 0$

$(y-x)^2\ge0$.

The final line is always true since a square is non-negative. Thus you can work your way back up to see the original inequality holds.

Comment: This does not really answer the question since it askes to derive one equality from the other. However I will not downvote it since it is a different view on the question.

Comment: ah. i didnt finish reading i guess because i thought they meant prove the equality using the equalities $x,y\ge 0$